# Optimally ALTER TABLE COLUMN SIZE

Tags: oracle, alter

Is there any feasible way to alter an oracle table column size ( we have one customer case where we need to increase the column size from 50 to 100), earlier I tried it with alter command with parallel option but unfortunately it took hours and i aborted it
From the logs I can see it has around 851,251 Mb data

Comment: It should be instantaneous because it only makes changes in its table meta data. It must be waiting for some kind of lock.